# What do you call the errors in the IDE that appears when you are writing code

Tags: java, intellij-idea

While coding Java in an IDE, you encounters errors (red marks in the IDE) when you're missing a semi-colon, mispell a variable, and etc. What is the name for those errors? compilation errors?

Comment: they usually result in compilation errors. However they could be syntax errors, logic errors, exceptions, ect, which makes the compile fail.

Comment: Your IDE is continually compiling your code every time you edit it.  It will highlight compiler errors (and usually warnings) during this process.  Yes, they are essentially compile errors.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize the IDE is continually compiling the code.

Comment: So compilation error does not only happen when you try to compile the code? It happens real time when you're editing the code in an IDE?

Comment: Compilation errors only happen when code is compiled.  **BUT**... your IDE is compiling your code automatically as you edit it.  This saves you the trouble of having to compile it yourself just to see the errors.